# How to loop through json and append inside append

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have json list with multiple owner. Each owner has their own list of timers.

I want to loop through the owners, and append the timers inside the owners that are already appended.

How can I do that?

## Edit: Changed #timer-list to #owner-list

Here is my json:

```
[
    {
        "ownerid": 1,
        "name": "Owner 1",
        "timers": [
            {
                "duration": "00:57:04.521586",
                "started": "2015-10-02T12:28:46+00:00",
                "completed_date": null,
                "paused_date": null,
                "objectid": 158,
                "paused": false,
                "completed": false,
                "resume_date": null
            },
            {
                "duration": "00:20:00",
                "started": null,
                "completed_date": null,
                "paused_date": null,
                "objectid": 172,
                "paused": false,
                "completed": false,
                "resume_date": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ownerid": 2,
        "name": "Owner 2",
        "timers": [
            {
                "duration": "10:00:00",
                "started": null,
                "completed_date": null,
                "paused_date": null,
                "objectid": 173,
                "paused": false,
                "completed": false,
                "resume_date": null
            },
            {
                "duration": "00:00:55",
                "started": null,
                "completed_date": null,
                "paused_date": null,
                "objectid": 176,
                "paused": false,
                "completed": false,
                "resume_date": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My js:

```
$.each(data, function(index, element) {
    console.log(element.ownername);

    $('#owner-list').append("<div id='timer_owner_" + element.ownerid + "'><h5>" + element.ownername + "</h5></div>");


        $.each(element.timers, function(index, element) {
            console.log(element);
        });            
});
```

How can I append to the `timer_owner_" + element.ownerid + "` ?

## Edit 2:

Here is how I want the html:

```
<div id="owner-list">

    <div id="timer_owner_1">
        <h5>Owner 1</h5>

        <ul class="timer-list">
            <li>Timer 1</li>
            <li>Timer 2</li>
        </ul>

    </div>
    <div id="timer_owner_2">
        <h5>Owner 2</h5>

        <ul class="timer-list">
            <li>Timer 3</li>
            <li>Timer 4</li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code :

```
$.each(data, function(index, element) {
    console.log(element.ownername);

    $('#timer-list').append("<div id='timer_owner_" + element.ownerid + "'><h5>" + element.ownername + "</h5>");


        $.each(element.timers, function(index, element) {
            console.log(element);
            $('#timer-list').append('<span>'+element.duration+'</span><br>');
        });    
    $('#timer-list').append("</div>");        
});
```

or this second way :

```
$.each(data, function(index, element) {
    console.log(element.ownername);

        var timers ='<ul>';
        $.each(element.timers, function(index, element) {
            console.log(element);
            timers += '<li>'+element.duration+'</li>';
        });  
        timers += '</ul>';

   $('#timer-list').append("<div id='timer_owner_" + element.ownerid + "'><h5>" + element.ownername + "</h5>"+timers+"</div>");     
});
```

Comment: `#timer-list` is the container I want all of the owners to be appended to. I need to append each timer-list to the specific owner div `#timer_owner_" + element.ownerid + "` I changed my question, so it would be a bit clearer.

Comment: explanation : when we open the div with id=#timer_owner_" + element.ownerid , we add also other informations in this example : duration in the span. at the end we close the div.

Comment: Copy pasted your answer, but the `<span>` are rendering outside the div. Could it be that jquery is auto completing the div?

Comment: i update the code and add a second more clear. hope this time will works.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a owner element first, append the timers to it and then append it to the owner list:

```
$.each(data, function(index, element) {
console.log(element.ownername);

var $ownerElement = $("<div id='timer_owner_" + element.ownerid + "'><h5>" + element.ownername + "</h5></div>");

var $timerList = $('<ul></ul'>).addClass('timer-list');

$.each(element.timers, function(index, element) {
        var $timerElement = element; // create you timer element here
         $timerList.append($timerElement);
    }); 

$ownerElement.append($timerList);

$('owner-list').append($ownerElement);       
});
```

I am sorry for the indenting, that is the first asnwer I give, hope it helps.